# Filtering search results in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, search, model, relationship

A user can subscribe to a package and the package can have many videos.

All paid videos are not visible unless the user subscribes to a package.

Please Note: The free videos are visible without subscription.

My problem is that when I want to apply search queries the user can view all the videos, which I don't want, I want the user to view only the videos he subscribed for.

Here is my code lines:

VideoController.php

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
  $keyword = $request->get('search');
  $perPage = 10;

  if (!empty($keyword)) {
    $videos = Video::where('video_title', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
        ->orWhere('video_file', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
        ->latest()->paginate($perPage);
  } else {
    $videos = Video::where('video_type', '=', 'Free')->latest()->paginate($perPage);
  }

  return view('video.index', compact('videos'));
}
```

video/index.blade.php

```
@foreach (auth()->user()->subscriptions as $subscription)
@foreach ($subscription->packages as $package)
    <h4>
        {{ $package->package_name }}
    </h4>
    @foreach ($package->videos as $video)
        <a href="{{ url('/video/' . $video->id) }}">
            {{ $video->video_title }} (Click to view)
        </a>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
@endforeach
@foreach ($videos as $item)
<a href="{{ url('/video/' . $item->id) }}">
    {{ $item->video_title }} (Click to view)
</a>
@endforeach
<div> {!! $videos->appends(['search' => Request::get('search')])->render() !!} </div>
```

Subscription.php model

```
  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

  public function packages()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Package::class);
  }
```

User.php model

```
public function subscriptions()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Subscription::class);
}
```

Package.php model

```
public function subscription()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Subscription::class);
}
public function videos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Video::class);
}
```

Video.php model

```
public function packages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Package::class);
}
```

Comment: how do you determine whether a user has subscribed a video?

Comment: @AnuratChapanond using a Subscription.php model with its migration

Comment: please provide those as well but basically you can add ->whereHas('subscription') to the query to only get videos with subscription.

Comment: @AnuratChapanond done please check the edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of checking for only keyword, you will have to add another clause that checks for subscription of the current user.

```
$videos = Video::whereHas('packages.subscription', function($query) {
        $query->where('subscription.user_id', auth()->id());
    })
    ->where(function($query) use ($keyword) {
        $query->where('video_title', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere('video_file', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
    })
    ->latest()
    ->paginate($perPage);
```

`whereHas` will check whether video has a subscription and subscription's user_id is the same as current user id (`auth()->id()`).

Comment: I get this error, "Undefined variable: keyword"

Comment: I add use ($keyword) to the closure.

Comment: The functionality you did worked for paid videos only, what if I want to apply for the free videos, is it possible?

Comment: Of course, you can write the same clause for another query.

Comment: Would you please type another one for free videos?

Comment: Please note there is another column I added which contains video_type 

Its either Paid or Free

Comment: You can just add the whole ->whereHas from the previous query to this free video query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228528/discussion-between-o-oedits-and-anurat-chapanond).